# init instance at runtime

Tags: java, factory

I use **Factory Pattern** to init a new instance at runtime.

**Questions:** Which version is the fastest? Are there any better patterns or solutions with Java 12 ?

```
/**
 * VERSION 1:
 * 
 * Uses Reflection with clazz
 * 
 * @param <T>
 * @param colorClass
 * @return instance type of derived colorClass
 */
public <T extends Color> T createInstance(Class<T> colorClass) {

    T t = null;
    try {
        t = colorClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return t;
}


/**
 * VERSION 2:
 * 
 * Uses Reflection with canonical name of class
 * 
 * @param <T>
 * @param colorClass
 * @return instance type of derived colorClass
 */
public <T extends Color> T createInstance(String colorClassName) {


    T red = null;
    try {
        red = (Color) Class.forName(colorClassName).getConstructor().newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return red;
}


/**
 * VERSION 3: (abstract factory pattern?)
 * 
 * Uses switch without reflection
 * 
 * @param <T>
 * @param colorClass
 * @return instance type of derived colorClass
 */
public <T extends Color> T createInstance(ColorName colorName) {

    T t = null;
    switch (colorName) {
    case red:
        return new Red();
        break;
    case green:
        return new Green();
        break;
    case blue:
        return new Blue();
        break;
    case black:
        return new Black();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return t;
}
```

**As suggested, I included Version 4 (which seems the best solution!):**

```
public enum ColorName {
    Red(ColorRed.class),
    Green(ColorGreen.class),
    Blue(ColorBlue.class),
    Black(ColorBlack.class);


    ColorName(Class<?> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    private final Class<?> clazz;

    public Class<?> getClazz() {
        return clazz;
    }

    public Color createColor() {

        Color c = null;

        try {
            c = (Color) this.clazz.getConstructor().newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: well reflection is usually hard to read so if you want others to be able to debug your code ID tend to go for the switch statement - Version 1 is defeinitely faster than version 2 though but probably about the same speed as versino 3 maybe a 1/100 of a millisecond faster :P

Comment: Forget "fastest";  Go for readability and maintainability first;  worry about speed only if it turns out to be a problem (and I can't see functions like this being a problem).  Personally, I would go for Version 4 - add a "getColor()" method to class ColorName;  Not only would this be fastest (minor issue), but far more importantly it means that as you add more ColorNames you are ensured that each ColorName does generate an appropriate Color (ie. you won't hit that "default" in Version 3).  Note also this option remains valid if ColorName is an enum.

Comment: Thanks! Good idea! I added Version 4 as suggested by racraman.